# Select option on selectpicker with codeception

Tags: php, laravel, codeception, bootstrap-selectpicker

Is it possible to select an option on a select box with codeception.
The select box is hidden - replaced with the selectpicker from bootstrap.

I've tried to click the button created by select picker, but codeception won't look into "title".

From documentation:

> Perform a click on a link or a button, given by a locator. If a fuzzy
>   locator is given, the page will be searched for a button, link, or
>   image matching the locator string. For buttons, the “value” attribute,
>   “name” attribute, and inner text are searched. For links, the link
>   text is searched. For images, the “alt” attribute and inner text of
>   any parent links are searched.

I've also tried to select through the hidden select - doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Which assertion are you using? This should be the one http://codeception.com/docs/modules/PhpBrowser#selectOption

Comment: I'm trying both - select option and click.
Trying xPath now - but nothing so far.

Comment: PhpBrowser does not support javascript, you have to use WebDriver with an actual browser or with phantomjs to test javascript functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Using jquery to assign the selected value on selectpicker

```
$I->executeJS("$('#user').selectpicker('val',130);");
```

further: http://codeception.com/docs/modules/WebDriver